# How to remove class using ng-class ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ng-class

http://plnkr.co/edit/6AEvKuyXai9LbcNjfluN?p=preview

I have 3 links, the first 1 has the `.active` class. When you click on 2 and 3, number 1 should lose the `.active` class. Right now if you click 2 or 3, they will update correctly, but 1 still has the active class on it :(

```
<ul>
  <li class="active"
      data-ng-class="{'active' : toggleObject == 1}"
      data-ng-click="toggleObject = 1">a click 1
  </li>
  <li data-ng-class="{'active' : toggleObject == 2}"
      data-ng-click="toggleObject = 2">a click 2
  </li>
  <li data-ng-class="{'active' : toggleObject == 3}"
      data-ng-click="toggleObject = 3">a click 3
    <br>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the class from the first li and instead set the toggleObject to 1 in the controller.

```
function HolaCtrl($scope){
  $scope.toggleObject = 1;
}

<li data-ng-class="{'active' : toggleObject == 1}" data-ng-click="toggleObject = 1">a click 1<br>
</li>
<li data-ng-class="{'active' : toggleObject == 2}" data-ng-click="toggleObject = 2">a click 2
<br>
</li>
<li data-ng-class="{'active' : toggleObject == 3}" data-ng-click="toggleObject = 3">a click 3
        <br>
</li>
```